# .NET Android App can read textfile in Documents only if created by itself

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mono

I'm writing an Android app in .NET using Avalonia. I'm attempting to read a textfile from the Documents folder, but am hitting an odd behavior: I can read the file only if it was created by the app itself, and in no other case. Below is an example with comments to explain:

```
private async void test_command()
{
    // Use Xamarin.Essentials to get READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    // The permissions are also listed in the manifest.
    // This succeeds, shows the prompt, & says "granted"
    var hasRead = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
    var hasWrite = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
    if (hasWrite != PermissionStatus.Granted || hasRead != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        show_notification_warning("Storage Permission denied");
        return;
    }

    var dirname = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/";
    var defaultFilename = "test.txt";
    var content = "This is some sample content";

    // Ask for a filename & write some text
    // (the dialog is handled by HanumanInstitute.MvvmDialogs).
    // This works.
    var promptVm = _dialogService.CreateViewModel<TextPromptViewModel>();
    promptVm.Title = "Enter filename to WRITE";
    promptVm.Text = defaultFilename;
    var success = await _dialogService.ShowDialogAsync<TextPromptWindow>(this, promptVm).ConfigureAwait(true);
    if (success.Value)
    {
        var writeFilename = dirname + promptVm.Text;
        using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(writeFilename))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(content);
        }
    }

    // Now ask for another filename to read.
    // If I read back the file I just created, it works.
    // However, if I enter the name of a file that I copied into the device
    // over USB, or created with a text editor app, it throws 
    // System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/test2.txt' is denied.
    promptVm = _dialogService.CreateViewModel<TextPromptViewModel>();
    promptVm.Title = "Enter filename to READ";
    promptVm.Text = defaultFilename;
    success = await _dialogService.ShowDialogAsync<TextPromptWindow>(this, promptVm).ConfigureAwait(true);
    if (success.Value)
    {
        var readFilename = dirname + promptVm.Text;
        using (var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(readFilename))
        {
            var readBack = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

At first it looks like a file permissions issue, but I've checked both the permissions & the owner and they're identical. i.e. if I have `Documents/test1.txt` and `Documents/test2.txt`, where one was created by the app per above (and can be read) and the other was copied onto the device or created by a texteditor app (and throws), both show the same permissions and the same owner.

Why won't Android let me open a textfile that I've copied into the Document folder or created with another app?

Comment: This is pretty normal behavior. On Android 11+ devices an app can only read its own files.

Comment: But I can i.e. copy a text file to the device & then open it in the text-editor app. Or if you copy photos onto the device, any photo viewer can see them. Or i.e. SyncThing can be pointed at any directory and sync those files, regardless of who created them. There's tons of cases where apps can read files that were created externally to that app...?

Comment: Indeed. Those apps obtained 'all files access'. Your app can go for that too. Or use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user choose such a file.

Comment: By "all files access", I assume ur referring to MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? i.e. the XODO pdf reader app has an internal file browser (i.e. not Android's file picker) that lets you navigate to and select any pdf file, and it can read even ones that it didn't create - without having to use the Android document chooser. And it doesn't have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission...?

Comment: I dont know that reader, sorry.

Comment: Putting compile and or target version lower might do it.

Comment: Yup, that did it - lowering the target version from 32 to 28 made it work properly. Shame Google feels the need to continually make things more & more of a hassle... :/